# How to paginate API response asynchronously with asyncio and httpx

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to get some data from a paginated API via post request using `asyncio` and `httpx`. API endpoint returns 149 listings and 52 listings per page I have to count the number of pages by `round(math.ceil(total_listings / int(listings_per_page)))` but I am only getting 3 listings script is scraping one listing from each page. Here is the code:

```
import httpx

import asyncio
import json
import math
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class InvenioHomes:
    

    cookies = {
        "Pl.userlang": "eng",
        "cookiesession1": "678A3E4BF4EF55FD1B56D8C35A31AC5D",
        "Cookie Management": '{"declined":"","all":"Cookie Management,DisplayDivasCookiesBanner,DisplayDivasCookiesBanner,Pl.userlang,clientdstoffset,clienttz,cookiesession1,dl_row_count,offset,stdtimezoneoffset","accept_all":"true","last_checked":""}',
        "DisplayDivasCookiesBanner": "yes",
        "ASP.NET_SessionId": "l1llpeh3pqk35ulpiq14gtrm",
        "offset": "-300",
        "stdtimezoneoffset": "-300",
        "clientdstoffset": "0",
        "clienttz": "Asia%2FKarachi",
        ".ASPXAUTH": "52AF9FB3157C0370E8F96C6A494E59D5C7D75A64D99E707C0BC8B6A888BF907246BD30CA63BF9B3A82916879220C30B28B1B3370EF3EF36E15A61CCDF9B7B080BF77DFEFA4E8CA264E114A3F103081C7EF86B79C095310AE705C79109D167DB1ACB9FA99D202D6F73EBD22E00D118A7899891031FE3C37AAC66AF9912BD00FA1",
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; Pixel 6 Build/SD1A.210817.023; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "Origin": "https://portal.inveniohomes.com",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Referer": "https://portal.inveniohomes.com/",
        # 'Cookie': 'Pl.userlang=eng; cookiesession1=678A3E4BF4EF55FD1B56D8C35A31AC5D; Cookie Management={"declined":"","all":"Cookie Management,DisplayDivasCookiesBanner,DisplayDivasCookiesBanner,Pl.userlang,clientdstoffset,clienttz,cookiesession1,dl_row_count,offset,stdtimezoneoffset","accept_all":"true","last_checked":""}; DisplayDivasCookiesBanner=yes; ASP.NET_SessionId=l1llpeh3pqk35ulpiq14gtrm; offset=-300; stdtimezoneoffset=-300; clientdstoffset=0; clienttz=Asia%2FKarachi; .ASPXAUTH=52AF9FB3157C0370E8F96C6A494E59D5C7D75A64D99E707C0BC8B6A888BF907246BD30CA63BF9B3A82916879220C30B28B1B3370EF3EF36E15A61CCDF9B7B080BF77DFEFA4E8CA264E114A3F103081C7EF86B79C095310AE705C79109D167DB1ACB9FA99D202D6F73EBD22E00D118A7899891031FE3C37AAC66AF9912BD00FA1',
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        # Requests doesn't support trailers
        # 'TE': 'trailers',
    }

    data = {
        "document_no": "307",
        "attrib_code": "307_bp_tile",
        "parms": 'arg1=[{"search_limit":"52","search_id":"","on_behalf":"8193","page_number":"1","sort_order":"villa_price~DESC","destination":"RGMYKONOS","license_options":"null","min_bedrooms":"1","max_bedrooms":"20","numberof_guests":"1","availability":"100"}]',
        "er_code": "",
    }

    api_url = "https://portal.inveniohomes.com/contentloader/CallDBMethod?source=actions/method_type&type=db&name=search"

    async def parse_listings(self, client, response):
        item = {}
        response_data = response[0]["result"]
        # print(response_data)
        for data in response_data:
            item["Guests"] = data["guests"]
            item["Rooms"] = data["bedrooms"]
            item["Bathrooms"] = data["bathrooms"]
            item["Short_Description"] = data["tagline"]
            item["Price"] = data["villa_price"]
            try:
                item["Location"] = data["geolocation"]
            except:
                item["Location"] = "N/A"
            item["City"] = data["city"]
        uuids = [
            "https://portal.inveniohomes.com/villa/" + uuid["bp_uuid"]
            for uuid in response_data
        ]
        # print(uuids)
        # print(len(uuids))
        for listing_url in uuids:
            html_listing = await client.get(listing_url, headers=self.headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_listing.text, "html.parser")
            marked_days_string = soup.select_one("#div_htmledit_224_calender")
            if marked_days_string:
                marked_days = marked_days_string.text.replace("\n", "")
                parsed_marked_days = json.loads(marked_days)
                item["Marked_calendar_days"] = [
                    d["pt_desc"] for d in parsed_marked_days
                ]
            amenities_string = soup.select_one("#div_htmledit_224_amenities")
            if amenities_string:
                amenities = amenities_string.text.replace("\n", "")
                parsed_amenities = json.loads(amenities)
                item["Amenities"] = [a["model"] for a in parsed_amenities]
            images_string = soup.select_one("#div_htmledit_224_gallery")
            if images_string:
                images = images_string.text.replace("\n", "")
                parsed_images = json.loads(images)["all_images"]
                item["Images"] = [i["path"] for i in parsed_images]

        return item

    async def total_pages(self, client):
        total_pages = None
        response = await client.post(
            self.api_url, cookies=self.cookies, headers=self.headers, data=self.data
        )
        json_string = response.json()
        json_bloc = json.loads(json_string)
        total_listings = json_bloc[0]["result"][0]["total_count"]
        parsed_param = json.loads(self.data["parms"].replace("arg1=", ""))[0]
        listings_per_page = parsed_param["search_limit"]
        total_pages = round(math.ceil(total_listings / int(listings_per_page)))

        return total_pages

    async def responses(self, client, pages):
        
        parsed_param = json.loads(self.data["parms"].replace("arg1=", ""))[0]
        for page in range(1, pages + 1):
            parsed_param["page_number"] = str(page)
            self.data["parms"] = "arg1=[" + json.dumps(parsed_param) + "]"
            response = await client.post(
                self.api_url,
                cookies=self.cookies,
                headers=self.headers,
                data=self.data,
            )
            json_string = response.json()
            json_bloc = json.loads(json_string)

            await self.parse_listings(client, json_bloc)
        # print(len(response_list))
        # print(response_list[0])
        

    async def main(self):
        tasks = []
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            pages = await self.total_pages(client)
            responses = await self.responses(client, pages)
            print(len(responses))
            for page in range(1, pages):
                tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(await self.responses(client, page)))

            results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            print(len(results))
            with open("invenio_homes_listings_data.json", "w") as jf:
                jf.write(json.dumps(results, indent=2))
            print("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = InvenioHomes()
    asyncio.run(scraper.main())
```

I'd like to fetch all the 149 listings asynchronously. Can anyone help me out how to do it so I can achieve the expected output? Thanks!